# Vuetify german umlauts not shown in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have installed a standard vue-cli 3 app.
Here is all ok and german umlauts (äöü) are shown.

After i install vuetify (vue add vuetify), all german umlauts are gone.

How can i enable german umlauts?
Is there a special config?

Thanks!

Edit: 
I think it is an Visual Studio 2017 Problem. 
I have testet a new project without Visual Studio 2017 and all is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer!!!

Visual Studio has a bug with file encoding in the editor.
Sometimes a file is interpreted as "utf-8-bom".

I added a .editor.config with

```
charset = utf-8
```

Thats for me !